# How to test if pixel is on the circle?

Tags: algorithm, drawing, geometry

I'm trying to draw shapes by checking if each pixel on the image is on the shape or not.

I've tried making for the circle:

```
public static boolean paintCircle(int x, int y, int r){
    for (int i=0;i<width;++i)
        for (int j=0;j<height;++j)
            if (isOnCircle(i,j,x,y,r))
                putpixel(i,j);
}
```

And isOnCircle() is just x^2+y^2=r^2

```
public static boolean isOnCircle(int testx, int testy, int x, int y, int r){
    int xx = (testx-x);
    int yy = (testy-y);
    return xx*xx + yy*yy == r*r;
}
```

The problem with this though is that not all points lie on the integer coordinates
 so many of them won't be drawn:

[image]

So in the end, how can I confidently test if pixel is on the circle or not?

Comment: The issue is that you want to draw points that are technically not on the circle, but should be drawn to represent the circle on a pixel-based screen. I personally don't know much about circle drawing algorithms, but you can try this link http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Midpoint_circle_algorithm

Comment: Is there any particular reason you're this rather than generating points that you know are on the circle?

Comment: @beaker Yes. I'm planning to draw multiple shapes which will in most cases overlap, so it's faster to pick the correct shape for each pixel than re-doing all the pixels for each shape.

Comment: Are you sure about it being faster? Assuming your circle has diameter `D` and your image is just large enough to contain the circle, your method checks `D^2` pixels rather than generating `~ 4*D` pixels.

Comment: @SmRndGuy Your analysis seems wrong. For every pixel you will need to check for every shape whether the pixel is part of the shape. The complexity of that is O(size of the bitmap * number of shapes). The alternative that we propose is O(sum of numbers of pixels for each shape) = O(average number of pixels per shape * number of shapes), which is strictly better. In fact it will be much much faster in practice as well because the rasterizing algorithms for the shapes have a very low constant factor. And as a bonus they produce better-looking output too.

Comment: Seems like if you're drawing, your best bet would be to use the [Painter's algorithm](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Painter's_algorithm) to an in-memory bitmap and then blit the result. That's likely going to be much faster than trying to decide in which overlapping shape each pixel belongs.

Answer (score 0):

You could check whether any point between this pixel and the next would be equal to the radius by checking if the one is smaller and the other greater. So something like: (untested)

```
return (xx*xx + yy*yy <= r*r) ==
       ((xx+1)*(xx+1) + (yy+1)*(yy+1) > r*r);
```

`(a <= b) == (c > d)` is equivalent to
`((a <= b) && (c > d)) || ((a > b) && (c <= d))`, which hopefully makes sense.

You could also try `xx+1, yy` or `xx, yy+1` instead of `xx+1, yy+1` - this should produce a few less pixels, if so desired.

---

Alternatively, you could generate the pixels in the circle rather than checking whether a pixel lies in the circle.

This could be done by looping over possible values for `x`, then solving `(x-x0)² + (y-y0)² = r²` to determine `y` (this can be done since you have `x`, `x0`, `y0` (the center of the circle) and `r` (the radius)). The `y` value could then simply be rounded to the closest integer.

Comment: The idea of testing the neighbour points rather then the actual one is good. But your implementation might fail i.e. the above idea `(xx*xx + yy*yy <= r*r) == ((xx+1)*(xx+1) + (yy+1)*(yy+1) > r*r)`is only true for the points that are in the lower right fourth of the circle. For the points from left upper corner (fourth) it should be `(xx*xx + yy*yy <= r*r) == ((xx-1)*(xx-1) + (yy-1)*(yy-1) > r*r)` for example.

Comment: The improvement would be: a) identify in which fourth is the point i.e. up-left/right, down-left/right. b) check several points. The reason to check several points are the particular cases for example if you want to check the point that is on circle and is exactly above the centre, then for some particular radius both `xx+1;yy+1` and `xx-1;yy+1` might be on the circle and hence only the points that are below and above `xx;yy` will deliver the needed information.

Comment: @AlexandruBarbarosie If `(xx*xx + yy*yy <= r*r) == ((xx-1)*(xx-1) + (yy-1)*(yy-1) > r*r)` is true for `xx = 5, yy = 5`, then `(xx*xx + yy*yy <= r*r) == ((xx+1)*(xx+1) + (yy+1)*(yy+1) > r*r)` will be true for `xx = 4, yy = 4`. So it may be off by one pixel. Perhaps `+.5` and `-.5` would be better. For really, really small circles, you may see the difference, although I doubt you will for larger circles - the added complexity one way or the other is unlikely to be worth it. I'm not sure if this addresses your second comment as well, as I didn't quite get that part.

Answer (score 0):

[Here](https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/mid-point-circle-drawing-algorithm/) you may find a fine implementation of a `O(x-y)` time complexity algorithm ( and of O(1) space complexity ) that applies the [midpoint circle algorithm](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Midpoint_circle_algorithm) as suggested by [@Khaelex](https://stackoverflow.com/users/3171863/khaelex).